# Does IDs from `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id` output are unique to a disk? - DELL PERC card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, hard-drive, zfs

Does output from `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id` can be used as a universal disk identifier?

I am currently trying to find a unique identifier that I can use to create a ZFS raidz pool using a unique identifier for each disk.

Potentially I want to use the same identifier to restore the ZFS pool after the system reinstall.

I have these requirements:

- Disks don't have partitions yet.
- Disks can be moved to another machine.
- Disks can change position slot in the same machine.

I'm currently using:

- Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS
- DELL PowerEdge R710
- DELL PERC6/i raid card
- 5 x 500GB DELL disks attached to raid card (sdb-sbf)
- 1 x 120GB SSD that is *not* attached to the raid card (sda)

PS. This RAID card doesn't have pass-through, so each disk is attached as an individual RAID0. Does it change the serial exposed to the OS?

Example output from `ls -lah /dev/disk/by-id/`

```
~$ ls -lah /dev/disk/by-id/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 960 Oct 23 06:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 160 Oct 18 18:53 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 ata-ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 18 18:54 ata-ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 18 18:54 ata-ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 scsi-0ATA_ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 18 18:54 scsi-0ATA_ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 18 18:54 scsi-0ATA_ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 scsi-1ATA_ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 18 18:54 scsi-1ATA_ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 18 18:54 scsi-1ATA_ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 scsi-36a4badb02b6020002666efd071e1c1a0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 scsi-36a4badb02b6020002666effa74599a2b -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 scsi-36a4badb02b6020002666f01c766dd5f0 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 scsi-36a4badb02b6020002666f04478ce7cc5 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 scsi-36a4badb02b6020002666f0627a912d6b -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 scsi-SATA_ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 18 18:54 scsi-SATA_ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Oct 18 18:54 scsi-SATA_ADATA_SP550_2G2520036769-part2 -> ../../sda2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 340 Oct 18 18:53 scsi-SDELL_PERC_6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 usb-iDRAC_LCDRIVE_20120430-0:0 -> ../../sdg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 usb-iDRAC_Virtual_CD_20120430-0:0 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 usb-iDRAC_Virtual_Floppy_20120430-0:1 -> ../../sdh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 wwn-0x6a4badb02b6020002666efd071e1c1a0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 wwn-0x6a4badb02b6020002666effa74599a2b -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 wwn-0x6a4badb02b6020002666f01c766dd5f0 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 wwn-0x6a4badb02b6020002666f04478ce7cc5 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Oct 18 18:53 wwn-0x6a4badb02b6020002666f0627a912d6b -> ../../sdf
```

Is `/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x6a4badb02b6020002666efd071e1c1a0` persistent if system is reinstalled? ('wwn' standing for World Wide Name)

Does it point to the disk or to the raid card slot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The World Wide Name is expected to be globally unique, and barring mistakes by a drive manufacturer it should be.

However, in the case of the single-disk RAID0 on your ancient PERC card, which was how people worked around its lack of JBOD support, the WWN refers to the *virtual* RAID0 disk, not to the physical disk. (And global uniqueness might not be possible, but they will at least be unique on your controller.) This should not cause you a problem in practice, but if it does, then buy a different HBA that supports JBOD.

Comment: Your consideration about replacing the PERC card is pretty on point, those cards are pretty old and don't offer JBOD. Thank you by the way.